# Sort elements returned from database in Play framework

Tags: html, list, sorting, playframework, ebean

I'm working on this playframework project. I have a list of ploegen and each ploeg has its punten. punten is an integer. I want to sort them by the value of punten. How can I do that?

This is the list I have now, it shows the plogen in the order they are stored in the database:

```
 <ul>
    @for(ploeg <- ploegen) {
        <li>
            @ploeg.naam
            @ploeg.punten
            @form(routes.Application.deletePloeg(ploeg.id)) {
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            }

        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: First, sorting should be done in the controller, in the code that accesses the database. What are you using to access the database - anorm? Are you using Scala or Java? Which version of Play framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [how-can-i-sort-a-list-in-play-framework-templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863556/how-can-i-sort-a-list-in-play-framework-templates)

Comment: @RobinGreen I'm using java.

Comment: And as for my other questions?

Comment: @t0mppa It isn't a duplicate, I'm not using json and that version of the playframework is much older than the one I'm using.

Comment: @RobinGreen I'm using ebean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robin said you should sort elements in backend.
You can do it like this:

```
Finder<Long, Ploeg> find = new Finder<Long, Ploeg>(Long.class, Ploeg.class);
List<Ploeg> ploegen = find.orderBy("punten asc").findList();
```

Comment: Works perfect. When you want to order in the other direction use `orderBy("punten desc")`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, sorting should be done in the controller, in the code that accesses the database. You can use [an EBean filter](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Filter.html). That will sort in memory. I'm not familiar with Ebean so I don't know if there is a better way.